# What technologies exist that allows to manage Ajax request request that take very long time?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I'm doing a request on an API that takes a very long time to execute (about 30 seconds to 4 minutes). Getting the user to wait is of course not a good idea, but I'm not sure about the web technologies that could allow to recontact the browser (subscribe) automatically after the request executed.

Any example of code, and pointers to the right techs would be really appreciated. I'm using aws APIs on the backend, and nextjs / redux on the frontend

Thanks